# How do I Verify installation requirements for Maximo 7.5 Installation?

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation

I downloaded Maximo 7.5 for Windows Server 2008 R2 x86-64 to create an ["Admin Workstation"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27035805&aid=1) (PDF). I'm getting an error when I click on "Verify installation requirements" after I run launchpad64 as Administrator.

I get an error that says:

CTGIN8125E : Administrative priviliges are required to execute this script.

I believe it has to do with running cscript.exe that is normally in c:\windows\system32

I am including video and screenshot.

[Video: Verify installation requirements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94MFDD3gaFE&feature=youtu.be)

[image]

Comment: Can someone with 300 rep add maximo or maximo-75 as a tag please? Thank you!

Comment: Seems that `maximo` or `maximo-75` are not available tags...

Comment: I can't create one because I don't have 300 rep, but it is also not a SO or SU question since it is specifically about installing it on the WS 2008 R2.

Comment: You are right, working directory for _run as administrator_ scripts is `C:\Windows\system32` if launched via right-click in file  explorer. A workaround:  _run as administrator_ CLI (`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` or `%ComSpec%`), change directory (for instance `pushd %temp%`), then `"C:\Windows\system32\cscript "path\launchpad64"` (change path and add extension properly). Ensure you do run both `cmd` and `cscript` in desired bitness which corresponds to folders `C:\Windows\system32` (64 bit) and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (32 bit).